# pgadmin connecting to postgresql ;error: server not listening

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, pgadmin

I am trying to make a new server registration in pgAdmin but I am getting this error:

"server is not listening"

The IP Address of the server is : X.Y.Z.W

And in pg_hba.conf I set accesses like:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
  # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
    local   all             all                                     peer
  # IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0          md5
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

 # IPv6 local connections:
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
```

when I run : su postgres
and then:   psql -h X.Y.Z.W -d test -U test 
There is no error.

how can I solve the error.

Thank you

Comment: Did you used the same machine for pgAdmin and psql ? Are you listening to every hosts in your `postgresql.conf` file ?

Comment: yes. in Postgresql.conf I set Listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Then it becomes tricky... You could try to re-install pgAdmin, and make sure its version is compatible with your server version. Also,  you should try to disable your firewall on client side if you have one. I don't see anything else yet.

Answer (score 1):

So I re-installed pgadmin3 and it worked fine.